# How to use a subquery in the FROM clause in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am asked this:

> Use a subquery in the FROM clause to only retrieve invoices from
>   chamber 'H' and the invoice amount of larger than 10000 and join the
>   result with the voyages table using the number column. Project to only
>   retrieve the boatname and the invoice amount of the join result. Order
>   by invoice amount.

So, I made this:

```
SELECT chamber =
        (
            SELECT      chamber 
            FROM        invoices 
            INNER JOIN  voyages ON  chambers.chamber  ='H' 
                                AND chambers.invoice > 10000 
                                AND invoice.number=voyages.number
        ), 
        boatname, 
        invoice 
FROM    chambers, 
        voyages, 
        invoices 
WHERE   chambers.chamber = invoices.chamber, 
        invoices.number = voyages.number
```

*This is the chambers table:*

```
#   chamber   name
1     A      New York
```

*This is the invoices table:*

```
#   number  invoice chamber
1   8300    9189    A
```

Yet it keeps giving me this error: `Query failed: near ",": syntax error`

Comment: You can't use `,` to separate `WHERE` clause statements.  You need to use `AND` or `OR`.

Comment: You should also stop using the implicit `JOIN` syntax.  You should *never* have a `,` in the `FROM` clause.  This ancient `JOIN` style has been deprecated for *over 25 years*.

Comment: @CSharper They won't.  But you should be asking the OP, not me.

Comment: @Siyah, how is someone from google supposed to find this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instructions say to put the subquery in the FROM clause, and you have it as an assignment to the chamber column. What you want to do is this:

```
SELECT b.boatname
        ,a.invoice 
FROM (SELECT number, invoice
        FROM invoices
        WHERE chamber = 'H'
            AND invoice > 10000) a
INNER JOIN voyages b ON a.number = b.number
ORDER BY a.invoice DESC
```

Comment: Haha, so simple! I was overthinking it. Thanks, I get the issue now.